# unicode string in C extension

Tags: c, ruby

I am writing a C extension for Ruby, and I need to accept a string as a parameter, and iterate the characters in the string. My code below works fine for ASCII characters, but it does not handle multiple byte characters, and outputs "garbage" instead. I could not find any sample code that would iterate over unicode strings. I would appreciate any pointers.

```
static VALUE test_method(VALUE self, VALUE text)
{
    char *pch;
    char *pch_end = RSTRING_END(text);

    for (pch = RSTRING_PTR(text); pch < pch_end; pch++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *pch);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an example of one way you could iterate over the characters:

```c
static VALUE print_single_char(VALUE s)
{
    char* pch;
    pch = StringValueCStr(s);

    // pch is now a pointer to a sequence of bytes representing the
    // character in whatever its encoding was. printf will work if the
    // console encoding is the same, otherwise you may get junk again.
    printf("%s\n", pch);

    return Qnil;
}

static VALUE test_method(VALUE self, VALUE text)
{
    rb_block_call(text, rb_intern("each_char"), 0, NULL, print_single_char, Qnil);

    return Qnil;
}
```

Note that once you convert any characters to C-strings you lose any associated encoding information. You might want to convert any input into a known encoding (such as UTF-8) before doing anything else:

```c
text = rb_funcall(text, rb_intern("encode"), 1, rb_str_new_cstr("utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`char` is only of size 1 so if you deal with multibyte characters you would have to use `wchar_t` instead and use the appropriate wide versions as well like `wprintf`.

Comment: if my string is UTF8 then I would need to check the width of every character. are there API for that?

Comment: So you mean that you get a pointer where you don't know in advance which kind of string that is?

Comment: `wchar_t` has a fixed size (32 bits?), but UTF8 strings can have characters of varying lengths (from one byte to, I think, five bytes).

Comment: "wchar_t has a fixed size (32 bits?)" - on linux; on windows utf16 is used, so wchar_t is 2 bytes and codepoint is 1 or 2 wchar_t.